# jQuery: Need to hide two "revealed" elements on mouseout

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a Drupal site with a standard jQuery/suckerfish-style menu, which I have modified to cause the final top-level LI to have some special functioning via jQuery. Specifically, on mouseover, it reveals a tab with reservations functionality. When the date input fields are clicked, jQuery UI datepicker activates. I need this reservations tab *and* the calendar to stay active so long as either are in-focus/hover/mouseover.

The HTML contained in the #reservations-tab div is here: http://pastebin.com/BPp4vS0R

I've not put it directly in this post because it's quite lengthy.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
 // Add div for reservations to display beneath "Stay" link when hovered.
  $('#reservations-tab').hide();
  $('.menulinkstay' || '#reservations-tab').mouseenter(function(){
    $('#reservations-tab').show().fadeTo(400, 1);
  });
  $('.menulinkstay' && '#reservations-tab').mouseleave(function(){
    $('#reservations-tab').stop().fadeTo(400, 0);
  });
  // Datepicker & Datepicker div hide
  $('.datepicker-input .field').datepicker();
  $('#reservations-datepicker-checkin .widget-icon').click(function() {
      $('#reservations-datepicker-checkin .datepicker-input  .field').datepicker('show');
}), $('#reservations-datepicker-checkout .widget-icon').click(function() {
  $('#reservations-datepicker-checkout .datepicker-input .field').datepicker('show');
});
});
```

I've tried adding `&& '#ui-datepicker-div'` to the first .mouseleave function; I've also tried multiple variants of doing it as a standalone line of code after the 'show' part of the datepicker invocation. I've tried using .hover, .mouseover, and .mouseleave.

In all contexts, I can get it to where the #reservations-tab is fading in properly, and the datepicker works, but either A.) The #reservations-tab div disappears when the UI Datepicker gains focus, or B.) The UI Datepicker appears and works as intended, but the #reservations-tab does not disappear moving the mouse entirely out of the area.

Much thanks in advance for any/all help.

Comment: If you replace `jQuery` with `$` it makes you code much easier to read

Comment: Filed under "Would if I could", as a matter of general discussion. Using the shorthand selector fails in my context due to factors outside my control. I'll edit this post, though, for convenience.

Comment: Sorry if I'm telling you what you already know but, generally your issue is because your `datepicker` is not part of your hover over so, entering the `datepicker` fires the `mouseleave` event. That said I can't think of a good solution.

Comment: Yeah, it was in that same enclosure several iterations ago. Same basic problem, just a different variation. I'll revisit it while I wait and see if others chime in. Thanks for trying!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK one solution I've used for similar problems in the past. Basically **If** you can structure your HTML like so:

```
<div id="reservations-widget">
 <!--widget code-->
</div>
<div class="mainDiv">

</div>
```

then you can structure your jQuery like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
 // Add div for reservations to display beneath "Stay" link when hovered.
  $('#reservations-tab').hide();
  $('.menulinkstay' || '#reservations-tab').mouseenter(function(){
    $('#reservations-tab').show().fadeTo(400, 1);
  });
  $('div.mainDiv').hover(function(){
    $('#reservations-tab').stop().fadeTo(400, 0);
  });
  // Datepicker & Datepicker div hide
  $('.datepicker-input .field').datepicker();
  $('#reservations-datepicker-checkin .widget-icon').click(function() {
      $('#reservations-datepicker-checkin .datepicker-input  .field').datepicker('show');
}), $('#reservations-datepicker-checkout .widget-icon').click(function() {
  $('#reservations-datepicker-checkout .datepicker-input .field').datepicker('show');
});
});
```

So now rather then the mouse leave function being fired whenever you hover over the datepicker, providing both your datapicker and hover overs our outside of `mainDiv` they should stay visible.

When the user leaves the drop down "area" they should enter your main div, thus firing the hover event on this and hiding your menus.

Hope that's explained satisfactory and helps.

Comment: Yes, Liam, it did. I had to finagle it a little bit more, but finally just set the .hover on the main page body, and all is well. I probably should have thought of that before, but it's been one of those "almost working" things where I got hung up on small details. 

Thanks so much!